# How to request JSON that have spaces in URL?

Tags: android, json, encoding, spaces

When I try the URL without spaces, it works perfectly.
However, when I add a space, it gives me the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in
>   path at index 79:
>   http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/Canada/Bachelors
>   Island Marine.json

When I tried it in the browser, it works.
PS: I tried encoding the URL and the same error occurred.

CODE:

```
    package com.example.elie.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
public class GetWeatherInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private  String mCity;
    private OnTaskComplete onTaskComplete;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get Country
    private static String url ;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_FORECAST="hourly_forecast";
    private static final String TAG_CONDITION="condition";
    private static final  String TAG_HOUR="hour";
    private static final  String TAG_DATE="pretty";
    private static final  String TAG_FCTTIME="FCTTIME";
    private static final  String TAG_HUMIDITY="humidity";
    private static final  String TAG_UVI="uvi";


    //The calling Activity
    private Activity mActivity;

    private WeatherInfo mWeather;

    //Country name
    private String mCountry;
    private JSONArray mForecast;

    //Constructor
    public GetWeatherInfo(Activity act,String country,String city)  {
        mWeather=new WeatherInfo();
        mCountry=country;
        mCity=city;
        mActivity=act;
        url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/"+country+"/"+mCity+".json";
        url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        Log.d("URL",url);
        this.execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting weather conditions...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                mWeather.setCityName(mCity);
                mWeather.setCountryName(mCountry);

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                mForecast = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FORECAST);

                // 1st element JSON object
                JSONObject firstElement =mForecast.getJSONObject(0);

                // FCTTIME JSON object
                JSONObject FCTTIME =firstElement.getJSONObject(TAG_FCTTIME);
                mWeather.setHour24(Integer.parseInt(FCTTIME.getString(TAG_HOUR)));
                mWeather.setDate(FCTTIME.getString(TAG_DATE));

                mWeather.setHumidity(Integer.parseInt(firstElement.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY)));
                mWeather.setUVIndex(Integer.parseInt(firstElement.getString(TAG_UVI)));

                mWeather.setCondition(firstElement.getString(TAG_CONDITION));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        onTaskComplete.setMyTaskComplete(mWeather);
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return mCountry;
    }

    public interface OnTaskComplete {
        public void setMyTaskComplete(WeatherInfo message);
    }
    public void setMyTaskCompleteListener(OnTaskComplete onTaskComplete) {
        this.onTaskComplete = onTaskComplete;
    }
}
```

ERROR:

> 02-12 18:43:04.098    5547-6459/com.example.elie.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 80:
>   http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/Canada/Addenbroke
>   Island.json
>               at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
>               at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.(HttpGet.java:75)
>               at com.example.elie.myapplication.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:68)
>               at com.example.elie.myapplication.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:34)
>               at com.example.elie.myapplication.GetWeatherInfo.doInBackground(GetWeatherInfo.java:77)
>               at com.example.elie.myapplication.GetWeatherInfo.doInBackground(GetWeatherInfo.java:18)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

Comment: Can you pose your code?

Comment: When you tried with an encoded URL, what did it end up being? And what was the error message then?

Comment: `replaceAll()` *returns* the modified string. You need to assign the result to `url`. BTW, you should be using `replace()` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape your url.
Should be like this: http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/Canada/Bachelors%20Island%20Marine.json

Supposing you have a String as your url , you could do:

```
 url.replaceAll(" " ,"%20");
```

**EDIT**

As many suggested, the most correct approach would be:

```
 url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

To avoid any problems like these in the future.

Comment: You need `url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");`

Comment: Pass `url.replaceAll` as the parameter to your request

Comment: HAHA sorry stupid question... it works now thank you.

Comment: @ElieKfoury: Instead of replaceAll use `URLEncoder.encode` like `url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/"+URLEncoder.encode(country, "UTF-8")+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(mCity, "UTF-8")+".json";`

Comment: The problem will happen again when country and city you have contain some other invalid URL character, then replaceAll will only replace spaces, but not the other invalid characters (and the code will break again)... You should use URLEncoder.encode to make sure that the URL is correct instead of temporary replaceAll solution.

Answer (score 2):

Space characters in URL must be encoded. Replace `' '` with `%20`.

Like this:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/Canada/Bachelors%20Island%20Marin.json
```

In general you should use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the URL.

```
url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: already tried that with replaceall(" ","%20"); and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spaces, try using '+' or '%20'.

e.g.
'http://api.wunderground.com/api/81eb946ab954bdcb/hourly/lang/q/Canada/Bachelors%20Island%20Marine.json'

Comment: It worked in the browser... but when i Used it in the app, it crashes.